# It's difficult to talk about times in chat

Tags: feature-request, chat, timezone

In chat, it's sometimes useful to talk about specific times. But that's hard with people from so many time zones around, and doing the mental calculations for how they shift.

Can we have a way of specifying a time (`18:00`), day and time (`Friday 4pm`) or date and time (`2016-10-29 22:00 PST`) in chat and it being parsed and translated into a something that shows it in terms of `UTC` and the reader's time zone?

I have not spent enough thought on how I expect this to work best – maybe two user scripts would be enough, and for the “Convert time stamps displayed on stackexchange websites to local time zone”, there appear to be some options on Stack Apps – but I just stumbled over the desire to express something like “Friday 23:00 to Saturday 8:00” in a time-zone aware way in chat for the third time, and I have noticed others struggling with expressing things like that in the past.

Comment: Express your times in UTC, specify a time zone, or link back to a chat post within your desired time frame.

Comment: The first two are not easy on the reader, the last one only applies to past events, not to plans for future chat events.

Comment: *It's difficult to talk about times in chat* ... and everywhere else in the world.

Comment: How about using a tool like http://www.timezone.me/en/meeting-planner or http://everytimezone.com/?

Comment: Until we fix time, the best you can do is probably UTC.

Comment: You could have a userscript to insert times in UTC, and another one to parse them in messages and add a tooltip with the corresponding time in your timezone. Of course it will require some tuning to handle the most common formats.

Comment: @ssube Isn't that how we fix time? — Anyway, an answer that suggests a good userscript setup and general format (don't some StackApps do some magic with “Z” after timestamps?) that I can refer others to will be acceptable. I may look at this myself in the future, I just don't have any experience with userscripts.

Comment: @Anaphory it could the fix, if anybody in real life would actually use it. Setting up a user script to swap ISO-8601 timestamps for the local time should be easy enough.

Comment: [We prefer calling it Iceland time](https://twitter.com/balpha/status/662306560031531009).

Comment: Reading this question sent me to the chat page, I was surprised to not find a time thereupon.  Why not just slap a clock on there (it's almost immaterial what time zone) and establish the convention that chat times are times according to that clock ?

Comment: I think its time for [Swatch Internet Time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swatch_Internet_Time) to make a comeback.

Comment: If this gets introduced, I predict: "I need to go to sleep, it's 5pm here." "That match was pretty nice, our team won 7:01 am." "That answer was posted just 11:30 am minutes later."

Comment: @Siguza: Wow, a very forward thinking +1

Comment: Time needs a perfect, flawless solution just like Unicode was for text.

Comment: @Kayaman So, we have four years to set up the Unitime Consortium! – Then they can do https://xkcd.com/927/.

Comment: UTC is the solution. Suck it up!